# Why does not Epilog work in my function in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

So in order to save some time, I wrote a function to plot a graph with a lot of default settings. I want to add a 0 tick to the Axes, so I added `Epilog` in the plot. However, the 0 does not seem to show up in the graph, and the `Epilog` does not seem to be working at all.

```js
LatexTextStyle[text_] := 
 Style[text, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "CMU Serif"]
StyledText[text_] := Text[LatexTextStyle[text]]
StyledTextPos[text_, posx_, posy_]  := 
 Text[LatexTextStyle[text], {posx, posy}]
NPlot[fns_, variable_ : x, xmin_, xmax_, ymin_, ymax_, 
  pltStyle_ : Default, epilog_ : {}, marginScale_ : 0.12, 
  fontSize_ : 18, xOffset_ : 10, yOffset_ : 10] := Plot[
  fns, 
  {variable, xmin, xmax}, 
  PlotStyle -> pltStyle, 
  AspectRatio -> Equal,
  PlotRange -> {
    {xmin - marginScale*Abs[xmax - xmin], 
     xmax + marginScale*Abs[xmax - xmin]}, {ymin - 
      marginScale*Abs[ymax - ymin], 
     ymax + marginScale*Abs[ymax - ymin]}
    },
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "CMU Serif", FontSize -> fontSize},
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}],


  Epilog -> {
    StyledTextPos["0", -xOffset, -yOffset]
    }
  ]

NPlot[fns = x^2 + 2 x + 1, xmin = -10, xmax = 10, ymin = -5, 
 ymax = 15]
```

Here is the graph that I got:

[image: The "0" does not show up on the graph]

When I tried other Epilog inputs, nothing appeared to be showing up.

Comment: Note there is a dedicated Stack Exchange site for Mathematica : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your offset defaults are positioning the 0 at {-10, -10}, below the vertical plot range.

These defaults position the 0 correctly:

```
NPlot[ ... , xOffset_ : 0.6, yOffset_ : 1] := etc.
```